# Proposed Question - Supercomputers - Looking on info for the running time of WRF on ES2 (Earth Simulator 2)

Tags: support, on-topic

I feel this question doesn't fit here - or possibly on any SE. Am I wrong?

> Can someone help me find information on "How FAST WRF runs on ES2?"?
>
> We know how fast ES2 runs, and how much memory it has and stuff... BUT
>   how long does it take to run WRF on ES2?
>
> ES2 and WRF Info -
>   https://www.jamstec.go.jp/es/en/system/performance_wrf.html
>
> WRF Info -
>   http://www.cray.com/Assets/PDF/industrysolutions/CMMACSWRFPoster.pdf
>
> For reference:
>
> - [ES2 (Supercomputer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Simulator)
> - WRF - Weather Simulation Program deliberately designed for ES2...

Comment: It certainly doesn't fit on Meta. :o

Comment: @Karan The question is about whether the OP can ask the question here.

Comment: @slhck: Certainly fooled me (and possibly others too). Could have been made more clear - looks an awful lot like it was posted in the wrong place. I have retracted my close vote based on your clarification.

Comment: @Karan yeah, I know what you mean. Cleared it up.

Answer (score 3):

Super User is about home computing and generally those kinds of problems normal users are facing. Certainly not about how a program runs on a supercomputer when you don't have access to the machine.

Also, how long such a program will run is quite hard to say without considering all possible factors. It's like asking how long a piece of string is.

The question is therefore unsuitable for Stack Exchange sites in my opinion.